# python number guessing question

Tags: python

```
import sys

print 'Content-Type: text/html' 
print ''

print '<pre>'
# Read the form input which is a single line
guess = -1 
data = sys.stdin.read()
# print data 
if data == []:
    print "Welcome to Josh's number game"
try:
    guess = int(data[data.find('=')+1:]) 
except:
    guess = -1 
print 'Your guess is', guess 
answer = 42 
if guess < answer :
    print 'Your guess is too low' 
if guess == answer:
    print 'Congratulations!' 
if guess > answer :
    print 'Your guess is too high' 
print '</pre>'
print '''<form method="post" action="/"> 
Enter Guess: <input type="text" name="guess"><br> 
<input type="submit">
</form>'''
```

Right now the program tells you if your guess is too low, too high or right on.  I want to add two more messages, one for when someone does not enter any input in the field. And another one for someone who enters invalid input (like a string or something) instead of a number.  My field 
data == [] is meant to show no input in the field, but it doesn't work as I thought. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.stdin.read()` will give you an empty *string* if there's no input, so `data == []` should be
`data == ''`.

The message for invalid input is probably best put inside the `except:` clause that you already have (you'll need to rearrange your control flow a bit so that becomes exclusive with the number-checking part).

Also, you may find [the `cgi` module](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/cgi.html) useful for what it looks like you're doing.

Comment: I've never heard of a cgi module. Can you explain it a little more?

Comment: I linked to the documentation for it.  Basically, it'll parse the HTTP POST data for you.

Comment: Can you tell me what the command is to validate code to make sure that it is a valid input.  Should I use data.strip() for that as well?

Comment: Also, thank you for the first post that you made. I still haven't gotten it to work but I think I'm headed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

`data` is a string and will never equal `[]`, which is a list. Try `data.strip() == ""`.

EDIT: It just occurred to me that you probably meant to use `sys.stdin.readlines()`, which *does* return a list. But instead of "fixing" this, I strongly recommend you follow @Zack's advice regarding CGI.